# How can I output a single CSS file from <style> tags inside of single file vue components using webpack and vue-loader

Tags: css, webpack, sass, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm currently using webpack to package all my `.vue` files but I'm struggling with also packaging the css associated with each vue component.

I'm using the `webpack.base.conf.js` which includes `vue-load.conf.js` and `utils.js` that comes from https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack.

I'm fairly confident I need to utilize `extract-text-webpack-plugin` but it's unclear how. I don't use webpack-dev-server but instead am doing 
`webpack --progress --colors --watch --config build/webpack.base.conf.js --output-filename built.js`